# How to save friends and their data in application

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, sharedpreferences

I am building a friends screen for my application but i have a question. How can i save friends and their data in application?

I have a screen with a listview, and a button and edittext. When you enter friend name in edittext and press button, it should save his name in a friends list, and add a row to listview.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Provide more details please.

Comment: Just want to store a string array in sharedpreferences.

Comment: Just execute the method extracting the data from TextView from the button's onClick method (set an onClickListener).